# Reprojection WFS GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, geoserver

I need to display my layer from geoserver on the map. I have problems with the projection system (EPSG:7749). I can't change the projection system with proj4 in my vector layer. I chose GeoJSON format because I will need to build a filter for the feature of my layer. Someone can help me?
`

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:7749', '+proj=aea +lat_1=34.0733 +lat_2=34.3833 +lat_0=34.2283 +lon_0=-112.7915 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs');
    ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
    console.log("Console: " + ol.proj.get('EPSG:7749'));
    var test = ol.proj.get('EPSG:7749');

    var urltest = 'http://myGeoserverIP/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=myworkspace:201910081246140571_Perimeters&outputFormat=application%2Fjson';

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        projection: test,
        url: urltest,
    });


    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
    });

    var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: test,
            center: [-8908887.277395891, 5381918.072437216],
            maxZoom: 19,
            zoom: 3
        })
    });
```

`

Comment: OpenLayers will atempt to transform the GeoJSON coordinates to view coordinates. Is your GeoJSON already EPSG:7749 ?

Comment: yes, i modify the layer projection upon loading. i used also the function ol.proj.tranform to modigy center, but nothing. what it's wrong? i'm new with openlayers and geoserver

Comment: Where are you expecting the map to be centered?

Comment: Use `dataProjection` and `featureProjection` on GeoJSON format. See API doc https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON-GeoJSON.html

Comment: i'm expect to see my layer near phoenix. it's not important where is centered the view.

Comment: The vector source doesn't have any projection property! You should add a projection to Geojson format. it has 2 property named `dataProjection` and `featureProjection`. You can check official document [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc).